# insert values to array column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table "details" with the below structure

```
id     status1      status2    names
 1    approved     rejected     NULL
 2    approved     rejected     NULL
 3    approved     rejected     NULL
 4    rejected     rejected     NULL
```

I want to insert values to array column "names" with default values {john,smith}

example :I need

```
  id     status1      status2    names
   1    approved     rejected   {john,smith}
   2    approved     rejected   {john,smith}
   3    approved     rejected   {john,smith}
   4    rejected     rejected   {john,smith}
```

It fails when i wrote

```
INSERT INTO details (names) VALUES(ARRAY['john', 'smith']);
```

Comment: Might be better asked in the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please specify "It fails" in greater detail. Do you get an error message? Which? Or does it behave in an unexpected way? Which? I also removed the unrelated tags, there is no PL/SQL and no dynamic SQL here. Please don't add tags unrelated to a question.

Comment: it behaves an un expected way.When i execute insert statement ,only one row is getting updated making rest of the columns null. i want to update column "names" with  {john,smith} for all the observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` creates completely new *rows* - but you want to change *existing* rows, so you need to use [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-update.html):

```
update details 
  set names  = ARRAY['john', 'smith'];
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to keep existing values with new ones:

```
UPDATE details SET names = names || '{john, smith}';
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Update existing `varchar array` of values.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with your `INSERT` statement provided your version is at least `9.3`, and names columns is of type `text[]` or `varchar[]`, i.e. *variable-length character string* :

```
create table details( id int, status1 varchar(25), status2 varchar(25), names varchar[]);
insert into details(names) values( ARRAY['john', 'smith']);
select * from details;

id     status1  status2   names
(null)  (null)  (null)  john,smith
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c69e6/1)

Due to your last comments, you need an `update` statement which sets only names column as *@a_horse_with_no_name* proposed, but not `insert` where `(null)` values are produced for the rest of the columns.

Comment: i don't want null values in columns (id ,status1,status2).I have 4 records in table and i want the names columns updated from null to {john,smith}

Comment: it behaves an un expected way.When i execute insert statement ,only one row is getting updated making rest of the columns null. i want to update column "names" with  {john,smith} for all the observations.

Comment: @user8545255 but, your question asks about failure during `insert`, if you need the help related to the issue as expressed here, please update your question due to these needs. By the way, if you don't want (null) values to be produced, then you need an `update` statement which sets only `names` column.