# How to store all the values in a row to array in postgresql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, row

I am having the following table

| Student Id | Subject A | Subject B | Subject C | Subject D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 87 | 76 | 100 |
| 2 | 90 | 100 | 64 | 71 |

This table contains information about the marks scored by students in various subject.

Now I need to store the marks in each row into an array. And I may add more subject column in future.

Now I need to change this

| Student Id | Subject A | Subject B | Subject C | Subject D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 87 | 76 | 100 |
| 2 | 90 | 100 | 64 | 71 |

into, something like

**array1**[98,87,76,100]
**array2**[90,100,64,71]

Comment: you mean this? https://dbfiddle.uk/OAh3BONB

Comment: You shouldn't have one column per subject to begin with - that's bad database design. You should have one _row_ per subject.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has an array data type. You can add a new column of this data type and copy your data into that format.

If your original table is defined like this:

```
create table scores (
  studentid int, 
  subjectA int, 
  subjectB int, 
  subjectC int, 
  subjectD int);
```

Then add a new column (this can be a one-dimensional or multi-dimensional array, reference https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html:

```
alter table scores add column subjectArray int[4];
```

And save the data into that column:

```
update scores set subjectArray=ARRAY[subjectA,subjectB,subjectC,subjectD];
```

Then you can select individual values like this:

```
select subjectArray[2] from scores where studentid=1;
```

Or select the whole array like this:

```
select studentid, subjectArray from scores where studentid=1;
```

Comment: Hi Valerie Parham Thompson. Thank You So much for your time. I still face a difficulty which is, I don't want to add the columns into the array manually, because in future I may add more subject columns to the table. I don't want to alter the code everytime I modify the columns of the table. Can you suggest some other ways?

Comment: The above is for converting existing data into an array. Could you share the code you are using to clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

This topic may have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938652/insert-values-to-array-column-in-postgresql), however you can also add a column of json type to save the data more easily. In your case, you would save the data as a string (as a valid json) and, by retriving it you would format it again to array.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) the doc about the json columns.